# Comparing two spreadsheets with two column combos for unique identifers

Tags: excel

I have to run this report at work that spits out data on labels we use for hazardous products.  I have one "Parent" file that contains all the data that should be in our system, and I will be generating a new report on what is actually in our system after releasing all the labels (we are switching from an older software version to a newer one)

So, there is a combination of two unique identifiers in the data for a label

Column A- Contains a Spec ID which is just a number that identifies a product, and in Column B-a Gen Variant of a Report- For Example "EU-GHS" or some other similar string.

To compare the difference between the two reports, what would be the optimal method?  I was thinking maybe concat the two columns, then use that combined identifier and use a function like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,Sheet2!C:C,0)),"Yes","No")
```

Assuming C2 is the concatenated unique identifier.

Would there be a simpler or more dynamic method for this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without additional column using array formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2 & B2,Sheet2!A:A & Sheet2!B:B,0)),"Yes","No")
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Or without array formula (works in Excel 2007 and later):

```
=IF(COUNTIFs(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2),"Yes","No")
```

for Excel 2003:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!B:B=B2)),"Yes","No")
```